# Is there a shorthand way to save a new database record in Yii2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, shorthand

Is there a shorthand way to save a new record when using Yii2 ActiveRecord?

Here are some examples from the docs:

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = 'Qiang';
$customer->save();
```

and...

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('customer', ['name' => 'Sam'])->execute();
```

It would be great if there was a shorthand method like...

```
Customer::create(['name' => 'Qiang']);
```

...but I can't seem to find that in the docs. Wondering if I'm missing something. Or would I need to create my own custom ActiveRecord class?

Answer (score 5):

Some ugly way of doing things

```
(new Customer(['name' => 'Qiang',]))->save();
```

If you need to return the model

```
($customer = new Customer(['name' => 'Qiang',]))->save();
```

> ".. Or would I need to create my own custom ActiveRecord class?"

Will be good solution for your case, however every time you generate a model from Gii, you'll need not to forget change parent class

Comment: Or you can adjust Gii template ;)

Comment: @Yupik yeah, wanted to write about it too =)

Comment: Ah nice! Yeah at least that's slightly shorter. Thanks for the fast answer and tips on managing that with Gii. 

Answer (score 2):

Creating record is actually more complicated in real world, because `save()` does not guarantee that record was saved in database. For example validation may not pass, the record will not be saved, and `save()` return `false`. Depending on situation you may want to throw exception in this case, or not.

I suggest to create factory class and encapsulate all necessary conditions, exceptions handling or defaults there - in long term it will be easier to maintain.

```
$customer = Yii::$app->modelFactory->createCustomer(['name' => 'Qiang']);
```